# ASP.NET Core dependency injection c# how to instantiate classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I created a class

```
public class DefaultLogin
{
    [Inject]
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager { get; set; }

    public DefaultLogin(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

I tryed to use the `[Inject]` Attribute for resolve the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. But it not worked. I'm not sure why it can be sometimes used like in classed derived from `ComponentBase`. Maybe someone know why?

So Inject Attribute not working. I remove `[Inject]` and make a constructor instead of `[Inject]` like in the code above. My Question now is how i can instantiate DefaultLogin class?
I can't do:

```
new DefaultLogin();
```

I not want to do this:

```
 serviceCollection.AddScoped<DefaultLogin>();
```

I want to do something like this (Extension class):

```
    public static void UseDefaultLogin(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var configuration = (IConfiguration) app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));
        var userManager = (UserManager<ApplicationUser>) app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>));
        string defaultUserUserName = configuration["DefaultUser:UserName"];
        string defaultUserEmail = configuration["DefaultUser:Email"];
        string defaultUserPassword = configuration["DefaultUser:Password"];
        if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync(defaultUserEmail).Result == null)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = defaultUserUserName,
                Email = defaultUserEmail ?? defaultUserUserName
            };

            IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, defaultUserPassword).Result;
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

`IConfiguration` can be resolved.
But `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` not,

Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[InfoApp.Repository.ApplicationUser]' from root provider

I call  `app.UseDefaultLogin();` at end of Configure method in Startup class.

Comment: _Something_ at the “top” of the IoC chain/graph has to perform some action as a “service locator style”. This is done (internally) by Controllers, for example. So, if DefaultLogin is injected in a controller, then it will be resolved there and in turn resolve it’s own dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go with the second method, with constructor injection.

To use a `DefaultLogin` object, you can do the same thing in the classes where you need it.

So let's say you have a `LoginController`. This should work:

```
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{

   private readonly DefaultLogin _defaultLogin;
   
   public LoginController(DefaultLogin defaultLogin)
   {
      _defaultLogin = defaultLogin;
   }
}
```

Note: General rule of thumb is to hold the injected references as fields, not as properties.